# Why logical 'explode' does not work in pie3?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, pie-chart

Observe this simple code:

```
data = 1:5;
explode = [true; false(4,1)];
pie(data,explode)
```

[image: explode 2D]

Now let's go 3D:

```
pie3(data,explode)
```

Oops! we get an error:

```
Error using pie3 (line 79)
Too many arguments or invalid cell array of character vectors.
```

But why? [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pie3.html#f30-537901) says:

> pie3(X, explode) specifies whether to offset a slice from the center of the pie chart. X(i,j) is offset from the center of the pie chart if explode(i,j) is nonzero. explode must be the same size as X.

It doesn't say anything about explode being numeric, just that it is interpreted as zero/non-zero values, which is exactly what logicals are, and indeed this works well for pie in 2D.

So why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr**: it looks like a bug or some inconsistency. Casting `explode` to any numeric type will solve it:

```
pie3(data,double(explode))
```

### [image]

**Why does it happen?**

Let's look at the argument checking of `pie3`. First, it processes the arguments, and puts all that is not a graphic object in a cell array `args`:

```
[cax,args,nargs] = axescheck(varargin{:});
```

Next (some unrelated lines are skipped), it omits the first input argument, and leave all the rest:

```
args = args(2:end);
```

So by now, if we call the function only with two arguments as written above, then `args{1}` is our `explode`. Now there is a series of checks to see *what* is `args{1}` (the explantions continue in the commentary on the code below):

```
if nargs==1 % this if false, nargs is 2
explode = zeros(size(x));
elseif nargs==2 && isnumeric(args{1}) % this if false, args{1} is logical
    explode = args{1};
    explode = explode(:); 
    if any(nonpositive)
        explode(nonpositive) = [];
    end
elseif nargs==2 && iscell(args{1}) % this if false, args{1} is logical
    explode = zeros(size(x));
    txtlabels = args{1};
    if any(nonpositive)
        txtlabels(nonpositive) = [];
    end
elseif nargs==3 && iscell(args{2}) % this if false, nargs is 2
    explode = args{1};
    explode = explode(:);
    if any(nonpositive)
        explode(nonpositive) = [];
    end
    txtlabels = args{2};
    if any(nonpositive)
        txtlabels(nonpositive) = [];
    end
else                             % we get here and get the error!
    error(message('MATLAB:pie3:TooManyArguments'));
end
```

Weird, but MathWorks didn't take into account that `explode` may be logical, as they did in `pie`. To me it looks like a bug, but maybe there is some hidden rationale here.

Comment: Not a bug, as `pie3` behaves as its documentation suggests, but clearly an inconsistency between `pie` and `pie3`. There are several other inconsistencies - for example, `pie` can accept data in the form of a categorical array, but not `pie3`. I think this would be a sensible thing to report to MathWorks as a feature request. The inconsistency is present in the current version R2017a.

Comment: @SamRoberts The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pie3.html) is either unclear (by not specifying the exact type of variable for `explode`)  or wrong (by letting you assume that any vector in the size of `x` will by fine). Either way, `pie3` does not behave exactly as one would infer from the documentation. That's why I call it a bug, though it's not _so_ problematic.